# Library checkout system

Tags: web-apps

I'm looking for a simple interface for library book checkouts. I would like it to be able to checkout books, and send auto reminders on the due date to whoever has the item checked out as well as a administrator's email.

I prefer that it is cloud hosted and free and it only needs to hold around 100 items.

Comment: I found several systems that appear to meet these requirements. See this search query: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=online+library+checkout+system+automatic+reminder

Comment: I see your search link, but I don't see much other than libraries with checkout systems. Feel free to let me know if you find something in particular that might match.

Comment: Wouldn't an appointment with a reminder on [Google Calendar](http://calendar.google.com) work? You have the ability to add guest emails and set up email reminders

Comment: That's a pretty good idea to use Google Calendar, but it wont have a centralized location of the status of books. If someone walks in and wants to checkout book x and it isn't there how do I check when it might come back? Or how do I check if it is just missing? I don't want to scroll through months of appointments to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a simple online database with two tables, one of books one of borrowers, there are numerous tools for doing this including Google Docs, [SODADB](https://sodadb.com/), etc., and using a simple python script daily to scan for those books that are due back the next day, (and those that are overdue), and generate an appropriate email to each borrower.

There is a walkthrough tutorial using Google App Engine [here](http://appinventorapi.com/program-an-api-python/).